# How to get a Count of the Items in my TFS Local Workspace?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2013, version-control, tfs

When I open my Visual Studio and get a solution from our TFS I have following message in the Output Window:

> TF401190: The local workspace [MACHINE_NAME;USER_NAME] has
>   158412 items in it, which exceeds the recommended limit of 100000
>   items. To improve performance, either reduce the number of items in
>   the workspace, or convert the workspace to a server workspace.

This is not an error, but a warning and I can work OK, although I feel there is a real performance hit during my work.

To resolve this I would like on one hand to "cloak" single branches/folders that I don't use. On the other hand I don't want to cloak to much and in general I want to know if there are some folders that have unnecessary many files in them.

Question: Is there a TFS Console/PowerShell Command, or something to retrieve a count of the items in the TFS Local Workspace that can be executed from my Visual Studio client machine? Something like the Treesize-App does, but for TFS?

I googled a little bit, but didn't find anything really helpful. [I found this on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892960.aspx) that confirms the reason why I am getting the message, but it doesn't provide any solution. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/247740/TFS-SDK-Workspace-Explorer-Statistics) is a guy that tried to do something as well, but the project never made it to codeplex afaik.

Our Team uses VS2013 Update 5 / TFS 2013 Update 5

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use Treesize on your local workspace?  Eg C:\TFS\MySuperLargeTeamProject)  You can also use non-recursive mappings with a trailing /* (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181378(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: Well, a local Treesize-Check would also show and count all non-managed files like builds, resharper settings, $tf artifacts etc... you know what I mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this e.g. with TFS API:

```
var uri = new Uri("https://tfs.mydomain.com/tfs/myteamprojectcollection")
var tpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(uri);
var vcs = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

var itemSet = vcs.GetItems("$/MyServerPath",RecursionType.Full);

Console.WriteLine(itemSet.Items.Length);
```

You can just put it into a console app, or if you change the syntax, it can be also called as a PowerShell script.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client")

$url = "https://tfs.mydomain.com/tfs/myteamprojectcollection";
$tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($url)
$vcs = $tfs.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer])
$set = $vcs.GetItems("$/MyServerPath", [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.RecursionType]::Full)

Write-Host $set.Items.Length
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Wish I could give more than 1 Upvote!

Comment: Does this return the total amount of items in $/MyServerPath or the total amount of items in the "Local Workspace"? I ran it against "$/" and got a number much higher than the number that Visual Studio displays whenever I first use TFS.