# How to see which items are in a TFS local workspace?

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to see which items TFS has in a local workspace? I'm getting error TF401190: The local workspace [name] has [amount] items in it, which exceeds the recommended limit of 100000 items. I've already deleted many files on my local machine, however, this does not actually lower the number of items in the "local workspace" in TFS. To actually lower the number, I'm following these directions:

> do a "Get Specific Version..." on the files [in Source Control Explorer], and select Changeset 1, the files will be deleted locally and the server will know this. [Source](http://www.woodwardweb.com/tfs_top_tip/tfs_top_tip_11.html)

But because I deleted many folders already, I do not know which files TFS is keeping track of in the "local workspace."

How can I see which items TFS is tracking in the local workspace so that I can do a get on Changeset 1 on them, to actually remove them from the local workspace?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046494/how-to-get-a-count-of-the-items-in-my-tfs-local-workspace) that asks about seeing the amount of items in the local workspace, but I don't believe it has been correctly answered. Possibly a PowerShell script could use the TFS API to see which folders "local workspace" items exist in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TFS Sidekicks, it's a TFS tool with some options, one of the options is to see your workspace (includes where the files in your local folders).

Download the tool from [here](http://www.attrice.info/downloads/index.htm).

[image]